# Generic method to subscribe to Ionic modal opening event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using Google Analytics to track the views that the user visits in my app.

When I start the GA tracker, I subscribe to the `app.viewDidEnter` event. So, any time the user enters a new view, the tracker catch it and register it. And I don't need to go through the code, view by view, putting any extra code. It's a generic way.

```
public startTrackerWithId(trackerId: string) {
    return this.ga.startTrackerWithId(trackerId)
    .then(() => {
        this.log.d("Google Analytics tracker started");
        return this.ga.enableUncaughtExceptionReporting(true);
    }).then(() => {
        this.app.viewDidEnter.subscribe((enteredView: ViewController) => {
            if(enteredView.component){
                let viewName = enteredView.component.name;
                this.log.d("Tracking view", viewName);
                this.ga.trackView(viewName);
            }else{
                this.log.d("Not tracking view ", enteredView);
            }
        });
    }).catch(e => {
        this.log.w("Error starting GoogleAnalytics", e);
    });
}
```

**But this doesn't include modals.** If the user opens any modal, the tracker doesn't track anything.

I was wondering if there is a generic way to detect when the user has opened a [Modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/modal/ModalController/). Something like an event to which I can subscribe, for example: `modal.present().subscribe(...)`.